# convert html links to be working in ios app

Tags: ios, hyperlink

I have iOS app and in one string, I have text and links like this

> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT **http:// mylink.com** TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

Is possible to recognize that link and do it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In UITextView, have a look at dataDetectorTypes

```
UITextView *test = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 150.0f, 320.0f, 200.0f)];
        test.text = @"Some text http://www.yahoo.com/ more text";
        test.editable = NO;
        test.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
        [self addSubview:test];
```

The link in that string will be blue and underlined, when tapped, it'll launch in Safari. You could detect more like this:

```
test.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink | UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
```